# preg_replace not matching

Tags: php, regex

I am running into an issue with preg_replace as I am not well-versed with regular expressions.

I am using [this tool](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm) to test but the replace isn't working as expected.

I have this input: `http://example.com/test-menu/d/C101`.
I am expecting this output: `http://example.com/test-menu/d/101`.  I simply want to remove the letter `C`.

(the `d` can be any alphanumeric character)

I am attempting to use this regex.

Here is the php that the site is generating:

```
<?php 
    $ptn = "/\/test-menu\/(.)\/C/";
    $str = "http://example.com/test-menu/d/C101";
    $rpltxt = "/test-menu/$1";
    echo preg_replace($ptn, $rpltxt, $str);
?>
```

I am not getting a match with my regular expression. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please consider using more descriptive variable names.

Comment: That was the php which the site was generating when I was testing.

Comment: My bad. The tool has probably hindered here, given that they quote `$rpltext` in double quotes, masking one of the main problems (where `$1` is evaluating before the replacement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

```
$ptn = '/(?<=\/test-menu\/.\/)C/';
$rpltext = '';
```

(which uses a positive lookbehind with `(?<= ... )`)

Or:

```
$ptn = '/(\/test-menu\/.\/)C/';
$rpltext = '$1';
```

(which captures the whole preceding string in the first submatch, all except the C)

Comment: Prettier: `#(/test-menu/./)C#`

Comment: Thanks.  I know these work but they are not working on the site I am building.  I think there is a bug elsewhere.

Comment: Hm, I used `$rpltext` instead of `$rpltxt`, might be it (should show with notices on), otherwise, yeah, somewhere else ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is the variables in `$rpltxt` were being expanded before the call to `preg_replace()`.

I also added the digits capture to the end and made the first capture specific to alpha characters. It's always good to be as specific as possible in your patterns.

```
<?php 
$ptn = "#/test-menu/([a-zA-Z])/C(\d+)#";
$str = "http://example.com/test-menu/d/C101";
$rpltxt = '/test-menu/$1/$2';
echo preg_replace($ptn, $rpltxt, $str);
```

**Update:** Changed regex delimiters per **cbuckley**'s *prettier* comment.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that `"$1"` is being expanded. Probably an `E_NOTICE` in there too.

Comment: Thanks. And a +1 to your comment.